# Smarty Master Pages

Tags: php, smarty

How can I create Master Pages like in ASP.NET using PHP and Smarty?

I want to have several content place holders in the master page and simply fill them with almost big HTML chunks. So I'm looking for a better approach than what I currently have.

```
$content =<<< eol
    <div id="home">
        <img src="images/jon.jpg" id="left-image" />
    </div>
eol;

$smarty->assign('content', $content);
$smarty->display('index.tpl');
```

Answer (score 2):

How about creating multiple templates and usning smarty `include`?

```
{include file="somethingelse.tpl"}
```

Answer (score 2):

U want to use template inheritance:

http://www.smarty.net/inheritance

layout.tpl

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{block name=title}Default Page Title{/block}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {block name=body}{/block}
    </body>
</html>
```

mypage.tpl

```
{extends file="layout.tpl"}
{block name=title}My Page Title{/block}
{block name=body}My HTML Page Body goes here{/block}
```

output of mypage.tpl

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        My HTML Page Body goes here
    </body>
</html>
```